# React: 'none' is not defined no-undef Delete Request

Tags: reactjs, api, request

there I'm pretty new to Reactjs, trying to follow this tutorial to build a component, meant to send a Delete request when clicking on the button!
However, I'm wondering what the element '' None represents? Almost down at the bottom of the code.
I'm getting the error message: 'none' is not defined  no-undef

[Link to tutorial](https://ordinarycoders.com/blog/article/react-axios-get-post-delete)

```js
import axios from "axios";
import { useState } from "react";
 
const DELETE = (props) => {
  const [message, setMessage] = useState(False);
 
  return (
    <div>
      {!message ? (
        props.data.length > 0 ? (
          props.data.map((value) => {
            return (
              <div onClick={() => deleteRequestHandler(value.name)}>
                <h3>
                  Name: {value.name}| 
                  Age: {value.age} | 
                  City: {value.city}
                </h3>
                <hr />
              </div>
            );
          })
        ) : None
      ) : (
        <h3>{message}</h3>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};
 
export default DELETE;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Does replacing `None` with `null` work ? In React, `None` means nothing by default. If the result is expected to be empty,  `null` should be used.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using "None", you can use null or a react fragment(i.e. <></>).